# The cardinality of the set of transcendental numbers is larger than that of the irrationals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

In a video, one guy said that there are more transcendental numbers than irrational numbers. I wonder why that would be. The only knowledge I have about infinities is that $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{Q}|<|\mathbb{R}|$. Can someone show me a  proof?

Comment: The irrational numbers and the transcendental numbers have the same cardinality (in that sense, there are the same "number" of each).  However, the transcendental numbers are a strict subset of the irrationals... perhaps that is what was meant?

Comment: Going in the direction of Xander; it would be interesting for us (and for you) that you define what you mean by "there are more..."

Comment: Shouldn't the title be the opposite?

Comment: Which video?$ {} $

Comment: @KennyLau It was a podcast by Joe Rogan with Neil DeGrasse Tyson here is a link (around 8:50 mark): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrkkOXC1WD0

Comment: @Yagger I corrected the typo.

Comment: Ok the source did say that, but this just goes to prove that you can't trust everything on a youtube video.

Comment: One additional word would make the statement true : The cardinality of the transcendental numbers is lager than the cardinality of the ALGEBRAIC irrational numbers. Maybe, this is meant, but it is important to mention this crucial word.

Answer (score 3):

One has to be careful with what "more" can mean in this situation. If $\mathbb T$ is the set of transcendent (real) numbers, then it is true that 
$$\mathbb T \subsetneq \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q \,.$$

So, in this sense there are more irrationals than rationals.

But, since the set of algebraic numbers is countable, it is easy to conclude that 
$$|\mathbb T|=|\mathbb R|=|\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q|$$
So, speaking in terms of cardinality, there are as many transcendent numbers as real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the comments, I think it can illustrative to reason why the transcendental numbers are uncountable.

Indeed, the transcendental numbers are defined as the complement of the algebraic numbers. And a number is defined as algebraic if it is the solution of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

But every polynomial can be thought of as a string of integer coefficients. For example, we could represent the polynomial $x^2+2$ as the string "(1,0,2)".

Furthermore, since the number of solutions is finite, as per the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), then we can enumerate the solutions of a polynomial. For example, we could represent $\sqrt 2$ as the second solution of $x^2+2$, or "(1,0,2),2".

This representation is not unique, but it is still surjective: every algebraic number can be represented in this way.

But every one of our custom code words is a finite list of integers! So the cardinality of the algebraic numbers is less than the cardinality of the finite lists of integers.

Since the set of finite lists of integers is countable, then the set of algebraic numbers must be countable too.

But if we substract a countable subset from an uncountable one, the cardinality of the uncountable set is unfaced.

So $|R| = |R\setminus Alg| = |Trans|$.